# unable to upload batch file in azure cloud

Tags: azure, batch-file, azcopy

I am uploading some files on azure storage account using azcopy command .its working fine but not able to upload files with .bat extension.
any suggestions are welcomed.

```
.\Azcopy.exe /Source:C:\Users\d44\Documents\test.bat /Dest:https://redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.file.core.windows.net/again/test.bat /DestKey:********  /Y
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: not receiving any errors but the screen displays transfer speed as 0 KB/s  . And after a while it just says transfer failed.

Comment: sir it is showing transfer failed but when i checked the azure account the file was uploaded but the data was changed(corrupted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround can be, first upload the file in a blob container, then copy the file from container to the file share.

`.\Azcopy.exe /Source:C:\Users\d44\Documents\test.bat /Dest:https://redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/test.bat /DestKey:********  /Y`

`.\Azcopy.exe /Source:https://redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/test.bat /Dest:https://redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.file.core.windows.net/<file_share>/test.bat /SourceKey:******* /DestKey:********  /Y`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide destination file name.

`.\Azcopy.exe /Source:C:\Users\d44\Documents\test.bat /Dest:https://redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.file.core.windows.net/again/ /DestKey:********  /Y`

Answer (score 0):

I think the command line should be like below:

```
.\Azcopy.exe /Source:C:\Users\d44\Documents\ /Dest:https://redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.file.core.windows.net/again/test.bat /DestKey:******** /Pattern:test.bat /Y
```

Comment: not working ....any other suggestions ?..and also i am getting this thing on my screen.. Incomplete operation with different command line detected at the journal directory

Comment: Could you share more information about "not working"? I can't help without further details.